# enlazar a una parte especifica de otro archivo desde un enlace <a>

Tags: html, html5

Tengo un botón que redirecciona a otra página de mi web. Pero quiero que no me envíe a la parte superior, sino a una parte específica del archivo. 
Estoy colocando el **id** en el **href**, pero no lo toma (cuando saco el **id** redirecciona perfecto, así que la ruta es la correcta, pero en la parte superior). ¿Qué puede ser?

Este es el enlace

`<li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html/#mesas">MESAS DULCES</a></li>`

Y este el elemento en donde quiero que aparezca

```
<article class="articulo">
    <div class="diseños" >
        <figure id="mesas" class="ejemploDiseños"><img src="imagenes/el punto logo.jpg" alt=""></figure>
        <div class="subeInfo">
           <h4>Mesas dulces</h4><h3>divertidas</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.adipisicing Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Hola parece que sobra el slach (/) antes de la almoadilla(#). Debes escribir: `href="cumples_y_eventos.html#mesas"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que eliminar el backslash de la url para que te funcione:

```
<li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#mesas">MESAS DULCES</a></li>
```

Esto porque con el slash  es interpretada como una ruta mas.